# SQL Error Explanation

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2008-r2

I created a temporary table and I want to update one column but I get an error message.

```
UPDATE #volume
SET    Pending = (SELECT t1.[esc],
                         t1.[Status],
                         CONVERT(DATE, t1.[Requested Date and time (hh:mm)]),
                         (SELECT count(*)
                          FROM   tmt t2
                          WHERE  t2.[ese] = t1.[eRfx/eAuction]
                                 AND t2.[status] = 'Pending'
                                 AND CONVERT(DATE, t2.[Requested Date and time (hh:mm)]) 
                                     <= CONVERT(DATE, t1.[Requested Date and time (hh:mm)])) cnt
                  FROM   tmt t1)
```

I am new to SQL Server can anyone explain me the below message

> Only one expression can be specified in the select list when the sub query is not introduced with EXISTS.

Raw Data is

```
## Date      Status ##    
----------
06/16/2014   Pending
06/17/2014   Completed
06/18/2014   Completed
06/19/2014   Pending
06/20/2014   Completed
```

output for pending status should be like below

```
----------
06/16/2014     1
06/17/2014     1
06/18/2014     1
06/19/2014     2
06/20/2014     2
```

Comment: What is so difficult in reading and interpreting the message? Only *one* expression is allowed, hence your select which you want to assign to 'Pending' must contain only one value and one row.

Answer (score 1):

The error is pretty self-explanatory as noted int he comments.  You have multiple items in the `select` in the subquery in a context where you can have only one item.  You are setting the item to a value, so only one is allowed.

It looks like you want to have the count of the pending statuses up to and including each date.  You can do this by using a correlated subquery:

```
UPDATE v
    SET Pending = (select count(*)
                   from tnt
                   where tnt.status = 'Pending' and
                         tnt.date <= v.date
                  )
    FROM #volume v;
```